# Continuity of: $f(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt[3]{x+1}, & \text{if }x\text{ $\ge 0$} \\ e^{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}} & \text{if }x\text{ $\lt 0$} \end{cases}$?

Tags: limits, continuity

What would be the best way of determining the continuity of the following function?

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt[3]{x+1}, & \text{if }x\text{ $\ge 0$} \\
e^{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}} & \text{if }x\text{ $\lt 0$}
\end{cases}$$

I would believe that it involves looking at the lateral limits but I am not too good in the process of this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$ x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x+1} $$
is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, and that
$$ x \mapsto e^{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}} $$
is continuous on $(-\infty, 0) \setminus \{-1\}$.  The function is not defined, and therefore discontinuous, at $x=-1$, which already presents a problem.  However, $f$ is continuous on the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,0\}$, and so it only remains to address continuity at zero.

A function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ (where we can assume here that $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$) is continuous at a point $a$ if

$$\lim_{x\to a^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^{-}} f(x) = f(a),$$

i.e. the left- and right-hand limits exist, are equal to each other (implying that the limit exists), and take the same value as the function itself.  Thus we need to check the one-sided limits and the value of the function at 0.

Note that both pieces of $f$ are continuous at zero, and so we can use the fact that the limit of a continuous function as $x$ tends to $a$ is the value of the function at $a$.  In particular
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \sqrt[3]{x+1} = \sqrt[3]{0+1} = 1 = f(0), $$
and
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} e^{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}} = e^{\frac{1}{(0+1)^2}} = e.$$
Since the limits don't agree, the function is not continuous at zero.

Comment: Isn't there also a discontinuity at $x=-1$ (well, it's not defined there).

Comment: but what values am I to use when evaluating the limits on both sides?

Comment: At $x=-1$ I can't see that it matters:  there's no $y$-coordinate there so it won't be continuous.  At this point, the limit is irrelevant (unless you care about whether or not the discontinuity is removable).

Comment: Ok, I understand but in the case of another equation, do I use any values when evaluating the lateral limit?

Comment: @Randall Oi!  I switched a sign.  You are correct.

Comment: You consider "all" of them, sufficiently close.  That is vague, but the best you can do over a 600 character message :)  Honestly, you make use of continuity "on one side" to handle each side (not always of course, but this is a good strategy in intro courses).

Comment: @XanderHenderson  I missed a similar discontinuity as a freshman 26 years ago and it never left me :)

Comment: @Randall I have corrected it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good. Since $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=e$, the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ doesn't exist and therefore $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but when I am evaluating the limits, do I use any values to left/right side of $0$?